# How to decode a Blob on the other side of a web socket?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have an application that sends audio data over a web socket to a client.

The audio is recorded using a `MediaRecorder`, then, combined with a JSON string into a `Blob` and sent from the browser, over to a Java based web socket server where it is then broadcasted and played on the client in another browser. The Java server does not, to my knowledge, in any way modify the data. It simply receives it and passes it along unchanged.

I am able to send and receive the audio data using these methods:

To send:
`socket.send(new Blob(recordedChunks));`

To receive:
`$("#source")[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);`

The problem I am now trying to solve, is that I would like to send along other data with the audio data, such as a user identifier and a list of clients for which the message is intended. I have implemented similar systems using sockets in C++, where first I would create a JSON string with the pertinent data, then create a binary stream starting by setting the length of the JSON string. When received, the client would first read the length of the command string, and then consider anything after that length to be the audio data.

I cannot however, for the life of me, wrap my head around how to achieve the same goal in JavaScript.

I have tried to do this:
`new Blob([ commandString.length, commandString, recordedChunks[0] ])`

Expecting to read the Blob as an array with 3 values on the other side, or to be able to read the array and parse out all three values. I'm stuck on figuring out how to decide when each value has been entirely read and then moving on to the next value. It does appear to be sent and received properly, the size both sent and received is the same.

One attempt to decode it was made by loading it into a DataView and iterating over the data, reading it as I went. However I'm unsure how to accurately capture the length, and then how to slice out the remaining data to put back into a `Blob` to send to `URL.createObjectURL`. I'm also not sure how to determine where to end reading the value that would tell me the size of the string. In C++, this was always the first 4 bytes of the message, but the first four bytes of this seem to be chosen at random and do not reflect the data I believe I have sent.

It seems that I'm working with a completely different architecture here, and I'm not sure where to move next from here.